# Class Based Listview Hangup how to query all

Tags: django, listview, django-class-based-views

I am trying to get ListView to work.
I would like a view that shows all of the objects in a model. like a index page.

When I lookup an object by it's DetailView the slug and page works.
This listview gives me the error:

> Page not found (404) at  /oferto/listview/

ofertoj.views

```
class OfertoListView(ListView):
    model = Oferto

class OfertoHome(ListView):
    model = Oferto

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = Oferto.objects.all()
        return context
```

urls.py

```
    url(
    regex=r"^$",
    view = OfertoHome.as_view(),
    name ="oferto_home"
    ),

url(
regex=r"listview/$",
view=OfertoListView.as_view(),
name="oferto_listview"
),
```

models.py

```
class Oferto(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=3000)

    slug = AutoSlugField(('slug'), max_length=128, unique=True, populate_from=('name',))
    tags = tagging.fields.TagField()

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='Ofertoj',blank=True, null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('oferto_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_tags(self):
        return Tag.objects.get_for_object(self)
```

parent urls.py

```
    (r'^oferto/',include('ofertoj.urls')),
```

Comment: Is this a typo? `self.request.Get.get("q")` there should be `GET` instead of `Get`..

Answer (score 0):

one thing is:

You're replacing the `context` with a QuerySet in your `oferto_home` view:

```
def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
    context = Oferto.objects.all()
    return context
```

Should be something like:

```
def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
    context = super(OfertoHome, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    return context
```

The ListView by default should retrieve all objects

---

Are your urls.py namespaced? If not, I believe, your urls could be

```
url(
regex=r"^listview/$",
view=OfertoListView.as_view(),
name="oferto_listview"
),
```

And the above url would be available at `/listview/`

if you want to prepend the appname you could create a url namespace or explicityly use the `oferta` in the url like:

`regex=r"^ofertta/listview/$",`

Comment: Thank you that fixed my oferto_home, that listview works fine, but the default listview still  gives me a 404 no oferto found.  I also do believe I have the url's namespaced

Comment: I guess I don't really know what namespacing is.  but look at my parent urls.py